# Session Management in JAVA : Basic Doubts

Tags: java, http, session

I am confused about Session Management in Java. When I browsed for a session creation, I found different answers over the web, which are correct in their own context. I have couple of basic questions on the same.

1) At the time of making a first HTTP request, does a browser create a session ID, and sends to the server, OR when an HTTP request from a browser lands on a server, for the first time, the server creates a Session ID?

2) Is JSessionID the session id? 
How this ID is set in a browser (i.e. Headers passed between a Server and a browser)?
How this ID is set in a server (internally in a server)?

3) If a session id is created by server/browser at the time of first HTTP request, then what and when does the HttpServletRequest.getSession(true) method do? 
What is the use of the method?

4) Is a sessionId from a server passed as a separate Header OR in a Cookies Header?

If the cookies is disabled in a browser, and a sessionId (JSessionId I guess) is passed by a server by any means (Separate Header or Cookies Header or any other form), what does a browser do? How is a session established in this scenario?

Do we explicitly need to write the code for appending a sessionId as a query parameter on a Server side?

How can we check on the server side, whether a browser has disabled cookies or not?

Comment: This seems to be a thousand questions rather than one. Read the JavaEE spec...

Comment: @BoristheSpider. After reading from different sources, I have these doubts. Also, these are not thousands questions, but, hardly 10 questions. You are free to answer or not the questions.

Comment: 10 questions is 9 too many for this format. They're also *questions*, not doubts.

Comment: I only say that because this question is probably going to get closed as it's not answerable in a reasonable length. There are answers to all these questions in the docs and you could also just experiment. This question is just too broad for this site.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think so - my answer is fairly complete and not too long; I feel the question was valid (it was phrased as many questions, but they had a very well defined common theme).

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I will repeat the question: how come the question is "too broad", if I could answer it completely in three paragraphs?

Answer (score 5):

1. Session ID is always created by the server. BUT if browser wanted, it could switch it for some other ID and server would have few means to find out (this is why session ids should be hard to guess and is generated randomly)
2. The server creates session id only when you (the programmer) try to use session for the first time. The overloaded `getSession` method is there so you can probe the existence of session without creating it.
3. The session id must be sent by server (at least once) to the client AND returned by the client (with each request). There are many ways to do it (you can think about the different ways as plugins, the exact technique does not matter for the actual session object).

The usual ways are:

- by a cookie; the name of the cookie value might be JSESSIONID, but it could be something else (it's configurable). On creation of session the server sends a `Set-Cookie` header (just once). From that moment on, due to how cookies work, the browser appends the cookie value to the standard `Cookie` header;
- by a request parameter. The server must append the parameter to each URL (GET) and as a hidden field to each form (GET or POST). It's not easy to automate this process (as forms and links could be generated by different libraries and pieces of application), and it's mostly up to the programmer. BUT some technologies (like JSP) have some support for adding this parameter (like `<c:url>` in JSTL). If you use some other presentation technology or generate urls for yourself, you will have to check how it works.

  1. Since some agents don't support cookies (frankly, the idea of a client that both requires sessions AND does not support cookies is rather dated), there is a neat trick: when the session is created, JSP tries to send the session id both ways: by a cookie (this works no matter what front-end technology you use) AND by a parameter. And when an answer comes back, the presence of cookie can be validated (if there is a parameter and no cookie - then the client does not support cookies, and JSP will try to send session by a parameter; if there is a cookie set, then parameters are not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Session is something that is handled on the server side rather on the client(browser). Whenever a GET or a POST request is made some kind of `handleRequest(HTTPRequest request, HTTPResponse)` gets invoked depending on the mapping you provide. Now you can get the session by `public HttpSession getSession()` method. Eg `Session session = request.getSession();`. It returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one([more](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)).

The Servlet HTTP session uses a cookie with the name `JSESSIONID` and a value that identifies the session.

The Servlet container keeps a map (YMMV) of HttpSession objects and these identifiers. When a client first makes a request, the server creates an HttpSession object with a unique identifier and stores it in its map. It then adds a `Set-Cookie` header in the response. It sets the cookie's name to `JSESSIONID` and its value to the identifier it just created.

The client receives these cookies and can store them somewhere, typically in a text file. When sending a new request to the server, it can use that cookie in the request's Cookie header to notify the server that it might have done a previous request.

When the Servlet container receives the request, it extracts the Cookie header value and tries to retrieve an `HttpSession` object from its map by using the key in the `JSESSIONID` cookie. This `HttpSession` object is then attached to the `HttpServletRequest` object that the Servlet container creates and passes to your Servlet. You can use the `setAttribute(String, Object)` and `getAttribute(String)` methods to manage state.

Most part is picket up from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896730/confusion-about-how-java-web-session-handeling-works-demystifying-cookies-and-h). You can go through very detailed tutorial [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting).