# Does java .invalidate(); destroy all sessions on a single user?

Tags: java, session, destroy

Does java .invalidate(); destroy all sessions on a single user?

Imagine that a logout button has a session.invalidate(); code to invalidate the session. What will happens if i  login on the same account with two different browser and i logout with just one? Will the session be invalidated for both browsers? What if i press on the "back" button from the browser i logged out. Will i be able to use the account in the browser where i did not clicked on logout or it will be disconnected from both browser?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between validate(), revalidate() and invalidate() in Swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510125/difference-between-validate-revalidate-and-invalidate-in-swing-gui)

Comment: The following code is used for logout

Session().invalidate();     
        res.setMessage(messagesPropertyReader.getPropertyValue(SESSION_CLOSED));

Comment: Sessions are not shared between two different browsers. A good reading for you is located here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896997/4222181

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about the back button then?

Comment: @JoeDings since the session ist destroyed in Server side, back button shouldn't work