# Getting session uuid set in redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I am setting a session attribute whenever a user is logged in like this `request.getSession().setAttribute(sessionUuid, user);`. `sessionUuid` is uuid which I am setting. But seems like this `sessionUuid` is not the session id, redis generates a session id by itself. Which looks like something like this

```
1) "spring:session:expirations:1597563240000"
2) "spring:session:sessions:expires:9dfef52d-d94a-4bcf-a08e-4a362b36f332"
3) "spring:session:sessions:9dfef52d-d94a-4bcf-a08e-4a362b36f332"
```

From my understanding the session uuid is `9dfef52d-d94a-4bcf-a08e-4a362b36f332`, for the attribute I have set.

What I am trying to understand is since redis generates a session id by itslef, then how am I supposed to get the redis session id, so that next time whenever user makes a request I can validate if the session is active or not ?

```
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("9dfef52d-d94a-4bcf-a08e-4a362b36f332") != null) {
    return (UserSessionComponent) request.getSession().getAttribute(session);
}
```

Or does the redis search all the session for that particular attribute ?

Comment: A session is bound to a single user and stores key-values(objects) across multiple requests; so you do not need the sessionId.

Comment: I know but you need the session id from frontend to backend to validate if the user is valid or not right.

Comment: '...validate if the user is valid or not...' do you only want to handle the request if there is a session? `request.getSession()` will create a new session if there is none, use `request.getSession(false)` this will return null if there is no session.

Comment: No, I am allowing em to login if there is no session.

Comment: `if (request.getSession(false) == null) { /* user has no session so redirect to login */ }` ?

Comment: Don't you think `request.getSession(false)` will return all the user's session ? I am looking to get the user session based on the session id set in redis

Comment: if you allow multiple sessions then a user may have multiple sessions, but then the user is still 'valid' isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but what's really holding me is, let's say we got `HttpSession session` from front end. And by doing `request.getSession(false)` how is this validating the session we got from front end to the redis server ? I didn't understand this part.

Comment: [Confusion about how java web session handeling works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896730/confusion-about-how-java-web-session-handeling-works-demystifying-cookies-and-h#:~:text=The%20Servlet%20HTTP%20session%20uses,stores%20it%20in%20its%20map.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it by experimenting. So for the SO readers we create a new session using this `HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);`, this will return a session or else it will create a new session if it doesn't exist.

And the `HttpServletRequest` will have the session whenever a user is making request or it may not have the session for the first time. This `request.getRequestedSessionId()` will give the same session uuid which is set on redis server, in this case it is `9dfef52d-d94a-4bcf-a08e-4a362b36f332` or else it will be null if it's first time.

Then using `request.getSession().getAttribute(session);` if it return null that means the session has been expired or else this will return the value.

By the way this is a good read on [spring session](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Next-Generation-Session-Management-with-Spring-Session/)